# How to use the native macOS file dialog in excel 2016?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2016

I despise excel 2016's custom file dialog, and I never want to have to use or see this:

[image: suck-ass excell 2016 custom file dialog]

Is there a way to tell excel to instead use the native file Open/Save dialog of macOS?